# google maps not loading correclty when first viewing website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When viewing a website I'm developing atm for a project I'm working on - it seems that the first time you visit the site - the google map located in the footer fails to load and only loads an image of the location and not the interactive map. However when reloading the page the map works fine :/.

I'm still quite new to JS and any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The website can be seen at http://www.kingsroad.net.au/

and the main footer page source can be seen at http://www.kingsroad.net.au/content/footerMain.php

Also kingsroad.net.au/js/general.js controls the loading of content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this:

```
function loadGoogleMap(){
  var mapOptions = {
    ...
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  setTimeout(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Hi wf9a5m75 - thank you for your help, I've edited my code with what you've suggested (is currently live on the website now) however the issue still seems to be occurring - I'm wondering if it has something to do with the image slider, as the first time the page is loaded this often happens as well: kingsroad.net.au/kingsroadJSproblem.png where the images only show the first inch or so and the rest is white.

Comment: i sorted the image issue out by setting the height manually in the CSS style - not sure why i didn't do that in the first place lol. However the google maps issue still persists. On my localhost the maps loads correctly with navigation and street view etc. however on the web server all i can get is the basic map after refreshing the page  :(.

Comment: Not sure how i fixed it, but I was messing around with my JS and doing some other stuff and it just works now -_-, wish it had of done that 6 hours ago lol. Thanks for the help wf9 :)